# How to get particular JSON Data into a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm a total beginner, so I've been kinda of banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out.

Basically, the code below displays json data from a url and displays it in a table. At the moment all 12 keys in the object are being displayed in the table.

What I would like to know is how would I go about displaying just some of the keys in the table. For example, how would I build a table that just has short, long, price and volume being displayed.

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Using Coincap.io API</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid fill-page">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-10">
                <div class="waitingDiv text-center">loading...</div>
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
                    <thead class="thead-dark"></thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://coincap.io/front",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        //only look at first 25 results...
        data = data.slice(0, 10);
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            if (index == 0) {
                $("thead").append("<tr id='tr-header'> ");
                $.each(Object.keys(data[index]), function(propertyName, value){
                    $("#tr-header").append("<th>" + value + "</th>");
                });
                $("thead").append("</tr>");
            }
            $("tbody").append("<tr id='tr-" + index + "'> ");
            $.each(data[index], function(propertyPosition, value){
                $("#tr-" + index).append(
                    "<td>" + data[index][propertyPosition] + "</td>"
                );
            });
            $("tbody").append("</tr>");
        });
        $('.waitingDiv').hide();
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("failed");
    });
});
<script>
```

Comment: What does the JSON data look like?

Comment: [  
   {  
      "cap24hrChange":-0.79,
      "long":"Bitcoin",
      "mktcap":119939101444.45686,
      "perc":-0.79,
      "price":6975.82477907,
      "shapeshift":true,
      "short":"BTC",
      "supply":17193537,
      "usdVolume":3782904194.04,
      "volume":3782904194.04,
      "vwapData":7031.397767247019,
      "vwapDataBTC":7031.397767247019
   },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for if propertyName is in an array of keys that you want to show.

```
var keys_to_show = ["short", "long", "price", "volume"];
$.each(Object.keys(data[index]), function(propertyName, value) {
    if (keys_to_show.includes(propertyName)) {
        $("#tr-header").append("<th>" + value + "</th>");
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me. But ill keep at it and post bak here if i figure it out.

Comment: I know it is not "perfect fit" for the question, but it is easy to understand behind logic it.